C# How to use generic parameter type as 'nested' type for interface?
I am just playing with some tasks for my mind and bumped into misunderstanding of some basic concepts. This code
namespace Game {

    public static class EventSystem {

        public class EventBase { }

        public interface IEventListener<in TEvent> where TEvent : EventBase {
            void OnEvent(TEvent ev);
        }

        private static Dictionary<Type, List<IEventListener<EventBase>>> _subscriptions = new();

        public static void AddListener<TEvent>(IEventListener<TEvent> listener) where TEvent : EventBase {

            if (!_subscriptions.ContainsKey(typeof(TEvent))) {
                _subscriptions.Add(typeof(TEvent), new());
            }
            var list = _subscriptions[typeof(TEvent)];
            list.Add(listener);
        }

        public static void RemoveListener<TEvent>(IEventListener<TEvent> listener) where TEvent : EventBase {
            if (_subscriptions.ContainsKey(typeof(TEvent))) {
                var list = _subscriptions[typeof(TEvent)];
                list.Remove(listener);
            }
        }

gives me the following errors at lines with list.Add(listener) and list.Remove(listener):
> Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'Game.EventSystem.IEventListener<TEvent>' to
> 'Game.EventSystem.IEventListener<Game.EventSystem.EventBase>'CS1503

I am trying to figure out why and how to fix this.
Cast (list.Add((IEventListener<EventBase>)listener);) gives me an exception at runtime:  System.InvalidCastException : Specified cast is not valid.
So, if I understand the case corrctly, IEventListener<TEvent> is invariant to EventBase, event thoug TEvent is actually EventBase. What I do not understand is 'why'?
PS. I am aware about the possible memory leaks, let's not discuss this) - just want to comprehend what's wrong with the generic type parameters

In your code  I don't see the advantage of using TEvent instead of EventBase. You do too much overengineering with the Dictionary.

@armagedescu
the idea was to have the specific imlementation of IVenetListener for the given event (or possible for several events). E.g.
public SomeClass : IEventListener, IEventListener { ...
...public void OneEvent(MeEvent1 ev) {
...public void OneEvent(MeEvent2 ev) {
And not to work through BaseEvent and use cast or pattern matching in one common OnEvent method.

Regarding the article Creating Variant Generic Interfaces (C#) you can't do it.
As a possible solution, you can do the following:
private static Dictionary<Type, object> _subscriptions = new();
    public static void AddListener<TEvent>(IEventListener<TEvent> listener) where TEvent : EventBase {

        if (!_subscriptions.TryGetValue(typeof(TEvent), out object? objList)) {
            Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(IEventListener<TEvent>));
            objList = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
            _subscriptions.Add(typeof(TEvent), objList);
        }

        var list = (List<IEventListener<TEvent>>)objList;
        
        list.Add(listener);
    }

    public static void RemoveListener<TEvent>(IEventListener<TEvent> listener) where TEvent : EventBase {
        if (_subscriptions.ContainsKey(typeof(TEvent))) {
            var list = (List<IEventListener<TEvent>>)_subscriptions[typeof(TEvent)];
            list.Remove(listener);
        }
    }


You could use pattern matching cast to circumvent this:
public static void AddListener<TEvent>(IEventListener<TEvent> listener) where TEvent : EventBase {
    if (!_subscriptions.ContainsKey(typeof(TEvent))) {
        _subscriptions.Add(typeof(TEvent), new());
    }
    var list = _subscriptions[typeof(TEvent)];
    if (listener is IEventListener<EventBase> baseListener) {
        list.Add(baseListener);
    }
}

However this will introduce certain performance decrease because of boxing for the pattern matching cast (details here).
